# Why is the context of Genesis 3:6 centred about the tree and less about the fruit?

Tags: genesis

Genesis 3:6

> And the woman seeth **that the tree is good for food**, and **that it is pleasant to the eyes**, **and the tree is desirable to make one wise**, and she taketh of its fruit and eateth, and giveth also to her husband with her, and he doth eat; `Young's Literal Translation`

The writer says Eve saw the 'tree' pleasant to the eyes, good for food and to make one wise, instead of the fruit?

Human nature is inclined to imitate so as to emulate, and so she eats as to become 'like' the 'pleasant and desirable tree'? This isn't my question.

Comment: Isn't it clear from verse 5 that the temptation was to *be as gods* and not to somehow be like the tree?  Am I missing something in your question?

Comment: @ user33515 that was precisely my observation. Isn't the text saying she ate so as to 'become' what she 'saw' in the 'desirable tree'? The eating was to become like 'gods,' knowing good and evil. Aren't these the things she 'saw' in the 'tree', that is knowledge of 'all' and a difference in the 'eyeing'?

Answer (score 1):

I think your point about Eve acting on what the tree itself offered is valid, but I think it was the devil (*serpent*) who turned her thoughts in the direction that they wandered.  The seminal event, in my opinion, was the serpent's tricking her into believing that she and Adam would *be as gods* if they ate of the tree.  What follows (*and when the woman saw that the tree was good for food, and that it was pleasant to the eyes, and a tree to be desired to make one wise*) seems to me as if she is trying to justify to herself the offense she is about to commit.  Ambrose describes the devil's thoughts:

> This, therefore, is my first approach, namely to deceive him while he
>   is desirous of improving his condition.  In this way an attempt will
>   be made to arouse his ambition.<sup>1</sup>

---

<sup>1</sup> *Paradise*, Ch. 12

Comment: Thxs for your observation, with +1. I have picked at bits that form the imagery in Genesis's creation so as to see it from another angle and it yields more questions than it answers, if normal 'trees', and that isn't the intent of scripture. Places like Ez 31's trees in the garden of God, the same 'tree' that was on the 'mount of God,' which signifies a 'congregation of gods', places like Gen 1:26 &Gen 3:22 when the Father cannot make mistakes. 
Psa 82:1...`God hath stood in the company of God, In the midst God doth judge`, etc, All these are exigencies for one view, and it isn't the literal!